# CartoDB: Center and zoom to stacked layer items/clusters with setView?

Tags: carto, clustering

Is there any way to setView on a location with several layer items on top of each other?

Mapbox example:
http://www.zeit.de/zeit-magazin/2015/16/regional-einkaufen-deutschlandkarte

Google Maps example:
http://www.kaffeemaschine-gastronomie.com/kaffeemaschine-gastronomie--Hersteller--s-rancilio.aspx